# How should I approach the logic for writing a piece of code that determines savings for a subscription package

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble calculating the savings for mobile phone plans for a book problem. I'd like to note that I've already finished the code for part one. It's part two where I'm having trouble. Okay, here are the book questions (for context):

> Part 1
>
> A mobile phone service provider has three different subscription packages for its customers:
>
> Package A: For $39.99 per month 450 minutes are provided. Additional minutes are $0.45 per minute.
>
> Package B: For $59.99 per month 900 minutes are provided. Additional minutes are $0.40 per minute.
>
> Package C: For 69.99 per month unlimited minutes provided.
>
> Write a program that calculates a customer’s monthly bill. It should ask which package the customers has purchased ans how many minutes were used. It should then display the total amount due.
>
> Part 2
>
> Modify the program in part 1 so that it also displays how much money Package A customers would save if they purchased packages B or C, and how much money Package B customers would save if they purchased Package C. If there would be no saving, no message should be printed.

**On part two, how can I calculate the savings for the plans?** I can't seem to implement them right. My initial thought was to subtract the overage cost of the total extra minutes from the total monthly bill, but I couldn't get that to work like I wanted. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    double minUsed, minLeft, extraMinCost, monthTotal, planSaveB, planSaveC;
    char choice;
    const double planCostA = 39.99, planCostB = 59.99, planCostC = 69.99, monthlyMinA = 450, monthlyMinB = 900;;
    

        cout<<"Enter your monthly package plan: Ex. A, B or C"<<endl<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<endl;
        
        cout<<"Enter the amount of minutes you used: "<<endl;
        cin>>minUsed;
        cout<<endl;

        if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')
        {
            
            minLeft=monthlyMinA-minUsed;
            if (minLeft < 0)

            {
                extraMinCost=minLeft*(-0.45);
                monthTotal=planCostA+extraMinCost;
                planSaveB = (planCostB-extraMinCost)-(-planCostB);
                planSaveC = planCostC - (planCostC-extraMinCost);
                cout << "Your total bill amount is: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << "$" << monthTotal << endl<<endl;
                cout << "You could save " << setprecision(2) << fixed << "$" << planSaveB << " if you switch to plan B or ";
                cout << "save " << setprecision(2) << fixed << "$" << planSaveC << " If you switch to plan C." << endl << endl;;
            }
            else if (minLeft >= 0)
            {
                monthTotal = planCostA;

                cout << "Your total bill amount is: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << "$" << monthTotal << endl;
            }

        }
        
        /*else if (choice == 'b'|| choice == 'B')
            {

                minLeft=monthlyMinB-minUsed;

                if (minLeft < 0)

                {
                    extraMinCost=minLeft*(-0.40);
                    monthTotal=planCostB+extraMinCost;
                }
                else
                    monthTotal=planCostB;

            cout<<"Your total bill amount is: "<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<"$"<<monthTotal<<endl;

}
        else if (choice == 'c' || choice == 'C')
            {
                
                
                monthTotal=planCostC;

                cout<<"Your total bill amount is: "<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<"$"<<monthTotal<<endl;
                cout<<"Current plan has unlimited minutes!"<<endl;


            }*/
        


        cout<<choice;

    return 0;
}
```

The relevant part is the choice a section of my code. I'll modify the rest when I can get that package a section right.

Comment: You should tag this properly with the actual programming language you are using (and not just with the mere tool/IDE you are using _for_ your programming.)

Comment: I'm sorry. Just added the appropriate tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you'll probably want to write a function like

```
float getPlanACost( int minutes ) { ... }
```

that returns the amount the customer would be billed if they had Plan A and used 'minutes' minutes. Then write similar functions for Plan B and Plan C. Use those functions to print your monthly bill, and to compute the available savings as requested.

A large part of software development is breaking a big problem down into smaller problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the switch statement and inside an if statement, which will make your code easier to understand and shorter.

Example:

```
switch (package)
    {
    case 'A':
    {
        if (time < 450)
            total = packageA;
        else
            total = ((time - 450)*rate_A) + packageA;
        break;
```